# a div/section is bleeding out of the website's actual frame size

Tags: css

I am trying to add "6 box" in a div/section of my website.  I am using WordPress and using custom CSS to complete the task.

I wanted to join all the 6 boxes of content, no space in-between. I am able to do that by applying custom css below.

```css
    .fusion-content-boxes .fusion-column{
        padding: 0px !important;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
```

```html
<div class="fusion-fullwidth fullwidth-box pmhomefull nonhundred-percent-fullwidth non-hundred-percent-height-scrolling"  style='background-color: #ffffff;background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px;'><div class="fusion-builder-row fusion-row "><div  class="fusion-layout-column fusion_builder_column fusion_builder_column_1_1  fusion-one-full fusion-column-first fusion-column-last fusion-blend-mode fusion-spacing-no pmhomefulltwo 1_1"  style='margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:20px;'>
     <div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="background-color:#ffffff;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;background-position:left top;background-repeat:no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;"  data-bg-url="">
      <div class="fusion-column-content-centered"><div class="fusion-column-content"><div class="fusion-content-boxes content-boxes columns row fusion-columns-3 fusion-columns-total-6 fusion-content-boxes-1 content-boxes-icon-on-top content-left pmcontentbox" data-animationOffset="100%" style="margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:60px;"><style type="text/css" scoped="scoped">.fusion-content-boxes-1 .heading h2{color:#ffffff;}
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover .heading h2,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover .heading .heading-link h2,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover .heading h2,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover .heading .heading-link h2,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more::after,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more::before,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .fusion-read-more:hover:after,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .fusion-read-more:hover:before,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .fusion-read-more:hover,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more::after,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more::before,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover .icon .circle-no,
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .heading .heading-link:hover .content-box-heading {
      color: #f05858;
     }
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover .icon .circle-no {
      color: #f05858 !important;
     }.fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box.link-area-box-hover .fusion-content-box-button {background: #b23735;color: #ffffff;}.fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box.link-area-box-hover .fusion-content-box-button .fusion-button-text {color: #ffffff;}
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover .heading .icon > span {
      background-color: #f05858 !important;
     }
     .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover .heading .icon > span {
      border-color: #f05858 !important;
     }</style><div class="fusion-column content-box-column content-box-column content-box-column-1 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 fusion-content-box-hover  content-box-column-first-in-row"><div class="col content-wrapper-background link-area-link-icon icon-hover-animation-fade" style="background-color:#f44336;" data-animationOffset="100%"><div class="heading heading-with-icon icon-left"><div class="image"><img src="https://i2.wp.com/www.pmlogos.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Logo-Design-Icon.png?resize=60%2C60&#038;ssl=1" width="60" height="60" alt="Custom Logo Design" data-recalc-dims="1" /></div><h2 class="content-box-heading" style="font-size:16px;line-height:21px;">Logo Design</h2></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><div class="content-container" style="color:#ffffff;">
<p style="font-size: 13px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus neque velit, vel congue arcu porttitor sed. Mauris non congue urna.</p>
</div></div></div><div class="fusion-column content-box-column content-box-column content-box-column-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 fusion-content-box-hover "><div class="col content-wrapper-background link-area-link-icon icon-hover-animation-fade" style="background-color:#e91e63;" data-animationOffset="100%"><div class="heading heading-with-icon icon-left"><div class="image"><img src="https://i0.wp.com/www.pmlogos.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/envelope.png?resize=60%2C60&#038;ssl=1" width="60" height="60" alt="Brand Identity Design" data-recalc-dims="1" /></div><h2 class="content-box-heading" style="font-size:16px;line-height:21px;">Brand Identity Design</h2></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><div class="content-container" style="color:#ffffff;">
<p style="font-size: 13px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus neque velit, vel congue arcu porttitor sed. Mauris non congue urna.</p>
</div></div></div><div class="fusion-column content-box-column content-box-column content-box-column-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 fusion-content-box-hover  content-box-column-last-in-row"><div class="col content-wrapper-background link-area-link-icon icon-hover-animation-fade" style="background-color:#9c27b0;" data-animationOffset="100%"><div class="heading heading-with-icon icon-left"><div class="image"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.pmlogos.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/bag.png?resize=60%2C60&#038;ssl=1" width="60" height="60" alt="Packaging Design" data-recalc-dims="1" /></div><h2 class="content-box-heading" style="font-size:16px;line-height:21px;">Packaging Design</h2></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><div class="content-container" style="color:#ffffff;">
<p style="font-size: 13px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus neque velit, vel congue arcu porttitor sed. Mauris non congue urna.</p>
</div></div></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><div class="fusion-column content-box-column content-box-column content-box-column-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 fusion-content-box-hover  content-box-column-first-in-row"><div class="col content-wrapper-background link-area-link-icon icon-hover-animation-fade" style="background-color:#673ab7;" data-animationOffset="100%"><div class="heading heading-with-icon icon-left"><div class="image"><img src="https://i0.wp.com/www.pmlogos.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/billboard.png?resize=60%2C60&#038;ssl=1" width="60" height="60" alt="Social Media Cover Design" data-recalc-dims="1" /></div><h2 class="content-box-heading" style="font-size:16px;line-height:21px;">Social Media Cover Design</h2></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><div class="content-container" style="color:#ffffff;">
<p style="font-size: 13px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus neque velit, vel congue arcu porttitor sed. Mauris non congue urna.</p>
</div></div></div><div class="fusion-column content-box-column content-box-column content-box-column-5 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 fusion-content-box-hover "><div class="col content-wrapper-background link-area-link-icon icon-hover-animation-fade" style="background-color:#3044b5;" data-animationOffset="100%"><div class="heading heading-with-icon icon-left"><div class="image"><img src="https://i2.wp.com/www.pmlogos.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/monitor.png?resize=60%2C60&#038;ssl=1" width="60" height="60" alt="Web and App Design" data-recalc-dims="1" /></div><h2 class="content-box-heading" style="font-size:16px;line-height:21px;">Web and App Design</h2></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><div class="content-container" style="color:#ffffff;">
<p style="font-size: 13px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus neque velit, vel congue arcu porttitor sed. Mauris non congue urna.</p>
</div></div></div><div class="fusion-column content-box-column content-box-column content-box-column-6 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 fusion-content-box-hover  content-box-column-last content-box-column-last-in-row"><div class="col content-wrapper-background link-area-link-icon icon-hover-animation-fade" style="background-color:#2196f3;" data-animationOffset="100%"><div class="heading heading-with-icon icon-left"><div class="image"><img src="https://i2.wp.com/www.pmlogos.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/edit-tools.png?resize=60%2C60&#038;ssl=1" width="60" height="60" alt="" data-recalc-dims="1" /></div><h2 class="content-box-heading" style="font-size:16px;line-height:21px;">Illustration and Graphics</h2></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><div class="content-container" style="color:#ffffff;">
<p style="font-size: 13px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus neque velit, vel congue arcu porttitor sed. Mauris non congue urna.</p>
</div></div></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><style type="text/css" scoped="scoped">
      .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .heading-link:hover .icon i.circle-yes,
      .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box:hover .heading-link .icon i.circle-yes,
      .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover .heading .icon i.circle-yes,
      .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover .heading .icon i.circle-yes {
       background-color: #f05858 !important;
       border-color: #f05858 !important;
      }</style><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div></div></div></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>

     </div>
    </div></div></div>
```

Now, this does the trick of joining all the 6 box, but the whole section bleeds out of the div/section by 20-30px. I tried a lot to solve this issue, but cant.

below is a link to screenshot of the issue here and represented the issue with red rectangles.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEUBr.jpg

Please help.

Comment: Can you show more code? You have added a snippet showing the CSS that you are trying to use as fix, but that is not really helpful to us without context. Can you paste in the code of the entire section in question along with CSS that you are currently using?

Comment: Added the new code in the actual question. Please keep in mind that the HTML I shared is generated by WordPress.

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't pasted enough code to be helpful. You copied the source of the section in question, but that doesn't give us all of the CSS that applies. Can you show us the CSS that is affecting the section? Or could you give us a link to the page where this is happening?

Comment: As Noah said, we can't know the issue without more code. Also, using `!important` is bad practice, you should use [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Thank you, Noah and Ovidiu! I was able to solve the issue with the bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap Grid classes to easily get items next to each other. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ There could be different reasons why the section won't contain the Grid items. It could be margin or padding which could push it down. I would suggest to use your browsers DOM explorer and hover to the section with the problem and try to play with the CSS values for example the padding, margins and widths as well as the Display property. I think the first thing to try is to try and add Display: inline-block in the CSS.

Comment: Hey Tig7r! Bootstrap grid classes worked. I just needed to identify the column class. It worked like charm!